# How to Display page in .net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have Create Module and Controller.. but i create 2 controller of one module.
Module Name " Leavepage"
Controller Name: Leavepages & ApprovedLeavepages..

Problem is.. when i login employee.. i send req to admin for leave. 
when if admin login he show employee requet then he approved req. but employee login did'nt show admin action Approved or not.. so how i show admin result in employye page..
my all code is done,model ok and controller ok just i want to add Approved controller.i mention the code plz help me

```
@if (Session["UserName"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleId"]) == 3)
{
    <li> @*add*@
        <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.4s" id="nav3">
            <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.diagram.png">
            <div class="text">
                @Html.ActionLink("Assigned Tasks", "Index", "AssignTasks")
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li> @*add*@
        <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.6s" id="nav4">
            <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.list.add.below.png">
            <div class="text">
                @Html.ActionLink("Time Sheet", "Index", "TimeSheetNew")


            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li> @*add*@
        <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.8s" id="nav5">
            <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.list.check.png">
            <div class="text">
                @Html.ActionLink("Approved Timesheet", "Index", "ApprovedList")
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        @*add*@
        <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.8s" id="nav6">
            <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.list.check.png">
            <div class="text">
                @Html.ActionLink("Approve Leavepages", "Index", "Leavepages")
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}
else if (Session["UserName"] != null && Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleId"]) == 1 || Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleId"]) == 2)
{

    <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.4s" id="nav3">
        <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.book.list.png">
        <div class="text">
            @Html.ActionLink("Project List", "Index", "Project")
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.6s" id="nav4">
        <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.location.add.png">
        <div class="text">
            @Html.ActionLink("Add Modules", "Index", "Module")
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="1.8s" id="nav5">
        <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.diagram.png">
        <div class="text">
            @Html.ActionLink("Assign Tasks", "Index", "AssignTasks")
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="2s" id="nav6">
        <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.user.add.png">
        <div class="text">
            @Html.ActionLink("Registration", "Index", "EmployeeRegistrations")
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="2.2s" id="nav7">
        <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.newspaper.create.png">
        <div class="text">
            @Html.ActionLink("View Timesheet", "Index", "TimeSheetNew")
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="contain wow bounceInRight " data-wow-delay="2.2s" id="nav8">
        <img class="icon" src="~/img/appbar.newspaper.create.png">
        <div class="text">
            @Html.ActionLink("ViewLeavepages", "Index", "Leavepages")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: what roleId belong to admin and employee?

Comment: Role ID Conntect to datase in 2 between 2 module

Comment: I assign role id admin =3 and emp roleid =2 in table

Comment: i want to use another created controller in _layout.cshtml